Flutter app is crashing while opening camera for scan
I am trying to scan a credit card with the package named  card_scanner: ^1.0.1-prerelease and   credit_card_scanner: ^1.0.5 . My code for the scan is
scanCard()async{

    try {
      var cardDetails = await CardScanner.scanCard(
        scanOptions: CardScanOptions(
          scanCardHolderName: true,
          //scanCardIssuer: true,
        ),
      );

      print(cardDetails);
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle any errors that occur
      print("Error scanning card: $e");
    }

  }

but whenever I call this function, the camera opens and crushes in a second.
I have set camera permission in my manifest as well. and the app has camera permission too. What is the issue then and how can I fix it?
Is there any other way to scan credit card information?

Please provide the error message you're getting on the crash.

Please provide more information on:

what version of flutter you are using?
what version of package you are using?
details on the debug console?

